# Review real android application code for learning

Tags: android

i study a course of development android application, i want to see a real professional code.

Is have a way to find in web a real working android applications and inspect their code for learning purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at
https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android

> Google I/O is a developer conference held each year with two days of deep technical content featuring technical sessions and hundreds of demonstrations from developers showcasing their technologies.
>
> This project is the Android app for the conference. The app supports devices running Android 4.0+, and is optimized for phones and tablets of all shapes and sizes

Answer (score 0):

You can explore online repository hosting platform [Github](https://github.com/) for Android projects and for others,too. There are huge number of good projects.

Answer (score 0):

Android provides official sample applications projects for each API version. You can download them via SDK manager and also from google's android developer site